# sonarqube github project analysis

Tags: github, sonarqube

I have a repository in my github account and i want to analyse it with sonarqube after each commit
I put the repository url in my sonar scanner properties : 
sonar.sources=https://github.com/rahma/JavaTest  but does not work .
any idea about this please ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the nature (confidential or public) of your project, you could use a **[GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)** like [`SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action)

That way, on each push, you would  scan your code with [SonarCloud.io](https://sonarcloud.io/).

But if you have a local SonarQube instance running, then you need the [Developer edition](https://www.sonarqube.org/developer-edition/), and check if your GitHub credentials are correct.

Comment: i use sonarqube bitnami (community ) in another machine running ubuntu  and i can access to sonarqube with the url generated in my windows machine, so i can't do that ?

Comment: @rheema You should be able to do that, but I don't know if it is available with the free edition, or only with the developer edition.